# Is there a simpler way of creating an array with a single element or empty if the element is null?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I somehow find it pretty lame to write the selection initialization:

```
updateSelectType(event) {
  this.setState({
    selectType: event.target.value,
    selection: this.state.selectedEvent ? [this.state.selectedEvent] : [],
    selectedEvent: null,
  });
}
```

So this is pretty straightforward, I wonder if the ternary can be simplified ? I don't want an array with a `null` element :)

Comment: not really, because you need a conversion to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach

```
updateSelectType(event) {
  this.setState({
   selectType: event.target.value,
   selection: [this.state.selectedEvent].filter(el => el),
   selectedEvent: null,
  });
}
```

Comment: I think this would be same as `[this.state.selectedEvent] || []` which can create an array with null in it `[null]`

Comment: This also filters out all falsey values, eg. `false`, `0`, `''`. I'd rather create a quick helper function if the syntax would bug me so much. ;)

Comment: @DarthJDG I'm actually adding objects so I really don't mind removing falsey values, as they would break the other components' propTypes anyway

Comment: I would no use this as it is not obvious what exactly it does on first sight.